# How to reduce the number of lines in your CSS file while keeping the same visual aspect (CSS code optimization)

Tags: html, css, optimization

**Hello !**
I'm looking for a way to optimize my code, I have the impression to have useless code in my css file, the visual aspect is cool, (despite the fact that it is not responsive), and that it is not very well aligned so if someone has advice to give me on how to optimize this code, how to improve it, or how to better align the different elements that make up my site I'm a taker!

**If it's not clear I can make things clearer here is my code :**

**HTML :** https://bin.readthedocs.fr/wighte.txt

**CSS :** https://bin.readthedocs.fr/athead.txt

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about how to improve code that works correctly belong on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly how to refactor without being on your end, but something I can point out is that you have several CSS selectors that effectively do the same thing:

```
.home-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
.store-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
.forums-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
.login-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
.register-a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
```

All of this can be replaced by:

```
a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
}
```

Since they are all anchor tags.

Comment: Thank you just for helping me, in fact I have a problem with the repetitions, but in the aspect of my site, I don't know if you could test my code, but when you launch the index.html, visually the site seems not very symmetrical : and I would have liked to solve that and that's why I thought that by optimizing my CSS I would be more comfortable with it, but I don't know what to edit to create these changes

Comment: There are some issues with padding that create a gap in your header on the right-hand-side, and it looks like you're also having issues centering some divs in the main section. I would try to avoid using padding in the x-direction on your header tags, but the best thing you could do is learn CSS Grid. You don't need to include any package since it's vanilla CSS, and it's a technology designed specifically for page layouts.If you are interested:
Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid
CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to find out about this, thanks again for the help